# Modify persistence.xml on runtime

Tags: java, jpa, persistence.xml

I'm developping a program that uses JPA, and I deployed it in a single jar. I wish to modify (or ask to the user, in an menú item) the configuration of the connection data with the database server.

It's possible to modify the data (user, password, ip) of the server "on the fly"?

(I apologize my bad english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPA spec doesn't allow for dynamic modification of persistence-units. Some implementations may provide an implementation-specific way of defining a persistence-unit dynamically. With DataNucleus JPA we do it as per the foot of [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jpa/persistence_unit.html)

Answer (score 3):

how about making a `HashMap<String,Object>` containing your options and passing it to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("unitName",map)`?

From the Docs:

> public static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory(String persistenceUnitName, Map properties)
>
> Create and return an EntityManagerFactory for the named persistence unit using the given properties.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29)

Comment: Works like a charm, doing that too, using Hibernate implementation.