# Change hibernate JPA properties at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence.xml

I usually use a *persistence.xml* to configure hibernate, via properties like

```xml
<properties>        
    <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="90000"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="90000" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
<!-- ... -->
```

However, I need to change one property at runtime (more specifically I need to adjust the value of `javax.persistence.query.timeout` at runtime). Therefore I tried configuring the session manually in situations where I need non-default properties, like that:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.addResource("persistence.xml");
config.setProperty("javax.persistence.query.timeout", "100000");
Session session = config.buildSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

However, this yields the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.boot.MappingNotFoundException: Mapping (RESOURCE) not found : persistence.xml : origin(persistence.xml)
```

Which makes sense, as the *persistence.xml* isn't a normal hibernate resource file. So how do I set the configuration on the basis of the *persistenc.xml* (I don't want to configure all the properties twice)? Or more generally, how do I reconfigure hibernate at runtime?

Note that this is similar to, but not duplicating (as it's more specific), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9614385/7700150).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be overridden/set per query:

```
query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 5000); // 5 seconds
```

If your query object is of type org.hibernate.Query you can do:

```
query.setTimeout(5);
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setTimeout(int)

Changing the properties in the EntityManagerFactory at runtime (To affect all queries) will not change the configuration in effect.
You can create a new EntityManagerFactory altogether if you want to, described here:
[Changing Persistence Unit dynamically - JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583881/changing-persistence-unit-dynamically-jpa)

Comment: Thank you! However, I don't have a hibernate query and the first option doesn't quite seem to work - shouldn't something like this:
`query.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 1);
query.getResultList();` 
timeout then (at least for a significant amount of data)?

Comment: It turns out my test just didn't timeout because it wasn't "complicated" enough - with a longer running query, the timeout works fine.